# Laravel migration to backfill uuids in every table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am attempting to create a database migration (MySQL) to backfill uuids in all tables (roughly 80 tables, some with 130k+ rows). To do this directly in MySQL, I can go table by table and run:

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET uuid = (SELECT md5(UUID()))';
```

which does add a unique UUID per row. If I loop through all tables and run a DB facade statement per table:

```
class BackfillUuidsIntoAllTables extends Migration
{
    protected $dbName;
    protected $tables;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbName = config('database.connections.' . config('database.default') . '.database');
        $this->tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        foreach ($this->tables as $table) {
            Schema::table($table->{'Tables_in_' . $this->dbName}, function ($table) {
                $tableName = $table->getTable();

                DB::statement("UPDATE $tableName SET uuid = (SELECT md5(UUID()))");
        }
    }
}
```

it executes quickly, but uses the same uuid for an entire table. Am I missing something in order to run this so every row actually gets a unique uuid?

Comment: Yeah, an `UPDATE` statement like that without a row constraint (like `WHERE id = 1`, etc) will update the whole table with the same value. Does your table still have a primary auto-incrementing column like `id`? You'd be able to do something like `foreach(DB::table($tableName)->get() as $row){ DB::statement("UPDATE $tableName SET uuid = (SELECT md5(UUID())) WHERE id = $row['id']"); }` (or similar) to generate an actually unique `uuid` per row.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I guess I'm confused that I can run that directly in the database per table and it updates each row with a unique uuid, but it doesn't work the same in the migration loop... My main issue with doing it like this is that it takes so long that it's actually crashing my pipeline (Jenkins to Azure VM).

Comment: Oh, now that is interesting. I would expect the functionality to be the same, since you're simply using a `DB::statement()`, but admittedly my knowledge of `UUID()` in MySQL is pretty limited. And yeah, depending on number of rows/tables being modified, I can see that being a pretty beefy process. Apologies, I don't have much more insight beyond that...

Comment: Couldn't you add the row's unique id to the `md5()`?  Also, It's not clear to me why you need that nested `SELECT`.  What about: `UPDATE <tablename> SET uuid = md5(concat(UUID(),id))`, assuming the primary key is `id`

Comment: @Quasipickle - Adding the row's id to the md5() worked perfectly! Yeah, the idea behind the subquery was for unique uuids per row, but since it wasn't working anyway, obviously not needed.

Comment: @MattLarson Great.  I'll make it an answer so I can get some more fake Internet points, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the row's unique id to the `md5()` call, it should generate a different string per row.  Also, the nested `SELECT` doesn't seem necessary.

This'll do the trick:

```sql
UPDATE
    <tablename>
SET
    `uuid` = MD5(CONCAT(UUID(), `id`))
```